# Seg faults with pthreads_mutex

Tags: c++, pthreads, segmentation-fault, mutex, cout

I am implementing a particle interaction simulator in pthreads,and I keep getting segmentation faults in my pthreads code. The fault occurs in the following loop, which each thread does in the end of each timestep in my thread_routine:

```
    for (int i = first; i < last; i++)
    {
            get_id(particles[i], box_id);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&locks[box_id.x + box_no * box_id.y]);
            //cout << box_id.x << "," << box_id.y << "," << thread_id << "l" << endl;
            box[box_id.x][box_id.y].push_back(&particles[i]);
            //cout << box_id.x << box_id.y << endl;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&locks[box_id.x + box_no * box_id.y]);
    }
```

The strange thing is that if I uncomment one (it doesn't matter which one) or both of the couts, the program runs as expected, with no errors occurring (but this obviously kills performance, and isn't an elegant solution), giving correct output.

box is a globally declared
vector < vector < vector < particle_t*> > > box
which represents a decomposition of my (square) domain into boxes.

When the loop starts, box[i][j].size() has been set to zero for all i, j, and the loop is supposed to put particles back into the box-structure (the get_id function gives correct results, I've checked)

The array pthread_mutex_t locks is declared as a global

`pthread_mutex_t * locks`,

and the size is set by thread 0 and the locks initialized by  thread 0 before the other threads are created:

```
locks = (pthread_mutex_t *) malloc( box_no*box_no * sizeof( pthread_mutex_t ) );

for (int i = 0; i < box_no*box_no; i++)
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&locks[i],NULL);
}
```

Do you have any idea of what could cause this? The code also runs if the number of processors is set to 1, and it seems like the more processors I run on, the earlier the seg fault occurs (it has run through the entire simulation once on two processors, but this seems to be an exception)

Thanks

Comment: The problems occur when cout is commented out

Comment: What does `get_id` look like?

Comment: void get_id( particle_t &p, boxPt &box_id){
 box_id.x = (int) floor(p.x/box_len);
 box_id.y = (int) floor(p.y/box_len);
} boxPt is a struc with an int x and an int y

Comment: Is the box[boxid.x] ever larger box.size()?

Comment: No, i've tested for it in several ways, so i'm pretty sure that is not the problem

Comment: Can you try compiling with -g to get debugging information and add stack traces for each thread.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you use one lock for all the boxes?

Comment: Yes, it does, so I am starting to suspect that I've done something wrong when i declare and initialize my locking array (i've tried to do it using a 2d array and vector as well, with the same problems). Can I dynamically allocate the number of mutexes the way I do?

Comment: Have you tried using valgrind yet? In addition to checking memory, Valgrind also has a race detection tool called Helgrind. Your error sounds like either a race or a memory overflow, and Valgrind can help you find both (though its race detection tool is not as useful as its memory checking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only an educated guess, but based on the problem going away if you use one lock for all the boxes: `push_back` has to allocate memory, which it does via the `std::allocator` template.  I don't think `allocator` is guaranteed to be thread-safe and I don't think it's guaranteed to be partitioned, one for each `vector`, either.  (The underlying `operator new` *is* thread-safe, but `allocator` usually does block-slicing tricks to amortize `operator new`'s cost.)

Is it practical for you to use [`reserve`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/) to preallocate space for all your vectors ahead of time, using some conservative estimate of how many particles are going to wind up in each box?  That's the first thing I'd try.

The other thing I'd try is using one lock for all the boxes, which we know works, but moving the lock/unlock operations outside the `for` loop so that each thread gets to stash all its items at once.  That might actually be faster than what you're trying to do -- less lock thrashing.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I moved the "superlock" to the outside of the loop, and that makes things go faster (but I guess it won't buy me the O(n/p) running time i'm supposed to get). I don't expect to have many particles in each box, normally 0 or 1. 5 would be a pretty conservative estimate. How do i use reserve to preallocate space? EDIT: I think I have a lot of memory available, so that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: I dunno, the speedup should come from the processing each thread does in isolation, right?  This piece is part of the inter-thread communication overhead, so your goal is to make it go as fast as possible, and it's quite possible that one-thread-at-a-time in the entire data structure will be faster than O(p) locks.

Comment: I added a link to `vector::reserve` docs to my answer.  Basically, you'd call it for each of the inner vectors during your setup phase in thread 0.  But when I say a conservative estimate, I mean you need to reserve enough space so that *no matter how many* particles end up in a box, `push_back` doesn't have to call the allocator.  Otherwise you haven't eliminated the bug, you've only made it less likely to bite.

Comment: This seems to work, thank you so much. One question i couldn't answer from the link: I will have to clear out the vectors for each time step throughout the simulations, either using clear(), resize(0) or pop_back() (right now i am using clear). will i still have the reserved space after any of these operations?

Comment: You're not guaranteed to still have the reserved space after `clear` or `resize(0)`.  I'm not sure about `pop_back`.  If it's practical to cycle through and call `reserve` again at the beginning of each time step (thread 0 would have to do this) then that would be the safest thing, I think.

Comment: Thanks. It is possible to do it with thread 0 (I was hoping to do it load balanced), but at least it's better to know :) EDIT: It seems to work even if I clear and don't reserve again

Answer (score 0):

Are the `box` and `box[i]` vectors initialized properly? You only say the innermost set of vectors are set. Otherwise it looks like `box_id`'s `x` or `y` component is wrong and running off the end of one of your arrays.

What part of the look is it crashing on?

Comment: box and box[i] are set to box_no (which is a variable determined by the input at runtime) by thread 0 before any other threads are created. This (should not be) isn't changed later. I'm not sure when the code crashes, except it is inside the loop i've posted above. As the code works fine when i'm printing, it's hard to tell. Any debugging tips are gratefully accepted